Projectile: Project specific commands/configurations
Is there a feature in projectile that allows me to run some configurations for a specific project?
For instance: I want to make it so that in project X, Y keybinding is configured. And when I close project X, keybinding Y is set to its original value.
Does something similar to this exist?

I later found: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html.
This allows you to have directory specific variables.
